# Django - Save and add another functionality

Tags: python, django, web, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to program a "Save and add another" functionality in my Django App.

I put an elif condition to a button. I can't find any helpful resources and references around the web especially with my set of codes. I have tried puting two returns inside the elif and putting the self.object snippet inside. Any suggestions what I can do? I am very new with Django. Please help.

**Views.py**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('skillsMatrixApp:index'))
    elif "another" in request.POST:
        #try 1
        #self.object = self.get_object()
        #url = self.get_success_url()
        #return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

        #try 2 
        #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('skillsMatrixApp:employee-add'))
        #return super(employeeCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return super(employeeCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**employee_form.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" formnovalidate name="cancel" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" formnovalidate class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    <button type="submit" formnovalidate name="another" class="btn btn-danger">Save and add another</button>
</div>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'employee/$', views.employeeList.as_view(), name='employee-list'),
    url(r'employee/add/$', views.employeeCreate.as_view(), name='employee-add'),
```

Comment: Does the cancel button work ?

Comment: Two returns doesn't ever make sense. What exactly do you want this functionality to do? Don't you just wnat to redirect back to the same page so the user can fill in the empty form again?

Comment: well first of all you should learn about what the return statement does because that's absolutely basic

Comment: Hi @InesTlili, yes, the Cancel button works just fine. :)

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, yes that's exactly what I am aiming for, but I can't find any helpful resources around the web that fits my logic and code.

Comment: Hi @Shinratensei, yes, I know the idea of return statements but my knowledge is very basic. This is noted, thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are confused about doing two things in the save and add new. So, I'll start from what you wrote:

1. Cancel, is Just a redirect to another page or to your home (or any other page).
2. Save. Is a save and redirect also to your home (or any other page)
3. Save and Add another, is a save and redirect to the same page.

I think you should do as follows in your `views.py`

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('skillsMatrixApp:index'))
    elif "another" in request.POST:
        # You can call the super to invoke the functionality without
        # returning the result.
        super(employeeCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('skillsMatrixApp:employee-add'))
    else:
        return super(employeeCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And a better version following DRY principle. you can do this: Thanks for @bruno comments

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    save_action = None
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('skillsMatrixApp:index'))
    else:
        save_action = super(employeeCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    if "another" in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('skillsMatrixApp:employee-add'))
    return save_action
```

Comment: You still have two calls to `super(employeeCreate, self).post()` in two branches, which is not DRY. You could very easily avoid this.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I've updated my answer. The idea is that I thought writing his code with the same style with pointing out the problem, would explain things to him better.

Comment: Thank you @AhmedHosny, thank you for your help. I am really new with this technology can you guide me through your answer like a dummy? Please? I really want to know what happened with your answer, just the syntax and code structure confuses me as it is. What does these codes do, please help? :)

Comment: If there's any error like form validation failure you should show them instead of a silent redirect. I suggest the predicate to be `if save_action.status_code == http.HTTPStatus.FOUND and "another" in request.POST`.

Comment: Also, for the most cases the user may probably just want to stay in the same creating page. In that case can simply use `HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info))`.

Answer (score 2):

The "save and add another" feature is just a matter of redirecting to the same page instead of redirecting to the default `success_url`. You could do it in the `post()` method itself, ie:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('skillsMatrixApp:index'))

    next = super(employeeCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if "another" in request.POST:
        next = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('skillsMatrixApp:employee-add'))
    return next
```

BUT this will not work as expected if the form doesn't validate (in which case the form should be re-rendered with errors). A better solution is to override `get_success_url()` - which will only get called if the post is successful - and check `self.request.POST` there:

```
class YourView(...):
    def post(self, ...):
        if "cancel" in request.POST:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('skillsMatrixApp:index'))
        return super(...).post(...)


    def get_success_url(self):
        if "another" in self.request.POST:
            return reverse('skillsMatrixApp:employee-add')
        # else return the default `success_url`
        return super(...).get_success_url()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @BrunoDesthuilliers, this answer works, thank you for your help. I am really new with this technology can you guide me through your answer like a dummy? Please? I really want to know what happened with your answer, just the syntax and code structure confuses me as it is. What does these codes do, please help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer for you make two generic class one CreateView and RedirectView. CreateView has method save your object(post) and return default page, and RedirectView has method where you set cancel url. Next in html form you can set a few form and add action to button. For example

```
 <form action="{% url 'create_view' %}" method="post">
      {% for field in form %}   
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <sup>{{ field.help_text }}</sup>
        {% endif %}
         {{ field.errors }}
         {{ field }}
     {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit">Save and add another</button><br>
      <button type="submit" formaction="{% url 'redirect_url' %}">Cancle</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi @GGG205, thanks for your answer, but I am using the generic form template using the {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }} feature. How do I incorporate this in my work? :)